# Number of solutions for $a$ of $x^2\equiv a \pmod3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find the all the numbers $a$ such that for $x^2\equiv a \pmod3$ there is:
>
> A. exactly one solution.
>
> B. two solutions.
>
> C. three solutions.
>
> D. no solutions.

**My attempt:**

$$1^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
2^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
3^2\equiv0\pmod3\\
4^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
5^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
6^2\equiv0\pmod3\\
7^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
8^2\equiv1\pmod3\\
9^2\equiv0\pmod3\\
\vdots$$

Answer for D. as we can see thator all $a\neq1,0$ there is no solution.

answer for A,B,C: $a=\varnothing$

I am not so sure about my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really only $3$ numbers in $\pmod 3$: $0,1,2$. Thus, we have:
$$0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
$$1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$
$$2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

Therefore:

A. Exactly one solution means $a=0$.

B. Two solutions means $a=1$.

C. Three solutions means $a \in \emptyset$.

D. No solutions means $a=2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check all square, it is sufficient to check all integers (mod 3), thus only three attempts:

${\begin{align} 1^2 = 1 (mod \ 3)\\2^2 = 1 (mod \ 3)\\3^2 = 0 (mod \ 3)\\ \text{Hence for } a = 0 (mod \ 3) \text{ one solution }\\a = 1 (mod \ 3)\text{ two solutions }\\ a = 2 (mod \ 3) \text{ zero solutions } \end{align} }$